# Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this query

Tags: sparql, ontology

[Image of prefixes with query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTUcQ.png)

when I remove filter it gives output but on adding FILTER nothing comes up.

```
SELECT distinct ?ID
WHERE { ?ID  rdf:type foaf:ID
    FILTER (foaf:has_Rel.WinRate >= "0.3"^^xsd:double)
}
```

After all the suggestions I came up with this query, but filter is still not working

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX foaf:    <http://www.semanticweb.org/abhin/ontologies/2021/11/stock_project#>
PREFIX xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace#>

SELECT ?ID 
    WHERE { ?ID foaf:has_AnnualReturn ?AnnualReturn;
        foaf:has_ExcessReturn ?ExcessReturn.
        FILTER (?AnnualReturn > "0.3")
        }
```

In filter I have also tried type conversion but that did not work
[snap of ontograph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKhPM.png)

[snap of an individual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HxU2.png)

Comment: what do you think the filter does? I mean, you have to select the value of the win rate in another triple pattern, then use that variable in your filter. SPARQL is not SQL, you cannot simply use a property like using a SQL column to refer to a value

Comment: @UninformedUser Can you plz help me with the updated query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter relies on a property `foaf:has_ref.WinRate` existing with certain values in your data. As you do not get any results, no such property is found.

With the snippet provided, the issue becomes clear:

```
<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#has_AnnualReturn"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#10-ID"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#0.5853214994439921"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>
```

The statements are about object properties, between individuals, where the IRIs happen to contain numbers. The SPARQL functions apply to numeric literals, not to individual IRIs, so the query will not find any matches because the input cannot be compared to the condition.

For your query to work, it is necessary that the properties be data properties, and instead of connecting an individual to another individual they should connect an individual to a literal.

The data should look something like this (adapting a different snippet of data from your file):

```
<DataPropertyAssertion>
    <DataProperty IRI="#has_AnnualReturn"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#10-ID"/>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.5853214994439921</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
```

Comment: ```SELECT ?ID ?AnnualReturn
 WHERE { 
             ?ID foaf:has_AnnualReturn ?AnnualReturn.
             FILTER (?AnnualReturn >= 0.3)
 }```   will this work. I am adding snippet too

Comment: I am facing same issue with this code. In the snippet you can see foaf:has_Rel.WinRate is object property and all ids have this object property. All double valuse are individuals of corresponding classes.

Comment: The properties you're using are showing as object properties in the screenshot you added. That sounds wrong, they should be data properties to give your queries a chance of success. Please add a snapshot of the actual triples rather than a screenshot of Protege.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mItUvBrgRD-2PLkcwBWE8Bglb2a0Jhcs/view?usp=sharing                                      This is drive link for ontology

Comment: Did you find any error in Ontology or any suggestions for query?

Comment: I've amended my response to show what the data looks like and what it should look like for your query to work. I hope that's enough to show what needs to change in the ontology. It's not "wrong", but it can't be queried the way you want to.

Comment: Can you please tell me a filter query for the existing ontology?

Comment: @ABHINAVSINGH not possible. The query is looking for values above a certain value and the ontology has IRIs, there's no builtin to compare the values of IRIs and numbers.

Comment: here is my updated ontology-     https://drive.google.com/file/d/13n85pFjAbmnaZNki9AwMn1ceWtHZF_nv/view?usp=sharing                 But I am still facing same issue. Can you tell me how to find ID's with Abs.Win_Rate grater than 0.25.

Comment: What does your filter look like? Abs_WinRate or Abs.Win_Rate?

Comment: It is Abs_WinRate in updated ontology.